# A circle function $f : S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ has degree $0 \iff f$ extends to a continuous function on the disk $D$. Explanation?

Tags: general-topology

The following theorem is an extension theorem concerning circle maps with 
degree $0$:

> $\boldsymbol{\sf THEOREM\ 9.9.}$ *A circle function $f:S^1\to S^1$ has degree $0$ if and only if $f$ extends to a continuous function on the disk $D$ (that is, if and only if there exists a continuous function $F:D\to S^1$ such that $F(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in S^2$).*
>
> ***Proof.*** Throughout the proof, we represent the points in the disk with polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$.
>
> $\quad$ First, assume that $f$ extends to a continuous function $F:D\to S^1$. Define a function $G:S^1\times I\to S^1$ by $G(\theta,t)=F(t,\theta)$. Since $F$ is continuous, so is $G$. Therefore $G$ is homotopy between the circle functions $G|_{S^1\times\{0\}}$ and $G|_{S^1\times\{1\}}$, implying that these functions have the same degree. The function $G|_{S^1\times\{0\}}$ is given by $$G|_{S^1\times\{0\}}(\theta)=G(\theta,0)=F(0,\theta)=F(0,0).$$ It follows that $G|_{S^1\times\{0\}}$ is a constant function and therefore has degree $0$. Thus, $G|_{S^1\times\{1\}}$ also has degree $0$. It is straightforward to see that $G|_{S^1\times\{1\}}$ is equal to $f$, implying that $f$ has degree $0$, as desired.
>
> $\quad$ Now assume that $f$ has degree $0$. Therefore there exists a homotopy $G:S^1\times I\to S^1$ such that $G(\theta,0)=c_0(\theta)$ and $G(\theta,1)=f(\theta)$, where $c_0:S^1\to S^1$ is the constant function sending each point $\theta\in S^1$ to the point $0\in S^1$. Define $F:D\to S^1$ by $F(r,\theta)=G(\theta,r)$. Since $G(\theta,r)$ is constant in $\theta$ when $r=0$, it follows that $F$ is well defined at $r=0$ and therefore is defined as a function on $D$. Furthermore, $G$ being continuous implies that $F$ is  as well. Finally, $F(1,\theta)=G(\theta,1)=f(\theta)$, implying that $F$ is an extension of $f$. $\tag*{${\blacksquare}{}$}$

It is hard to me to understand it, though! Would someone please guide me about the following questions:

1- Why since $F(t,\theta)$ is continuous, so is $G(\theta,t)$? It seems intuitively correct, but I can't prove it. What's a rigorous proof of the statement?

2- In last paragraph: $f$ has degree $0$, what's its business to each of these two statements: $G(\theta,0)=c_0(\theta)$ and $G(\theta,1)=f(\theta)$?

3- In last paragraph: Why since $F(t,\theta)$ is well defined in $r=0$, so it is well defined on entire disk $D$? This time even I don't get it at least intuitively also! What's a rigorous proof of the statement?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - As $F$ is continuous, and $G$ is just obtained by switching the coordinates of $F$, $G$ must be continuous. A 'formal' proof of this can be done by using that $F$ is continuous. For example, let $ \delta$ be small enough, and $|(t,\theta) - (r,\rho)| < \delta$. Then $|G(\theta,t)-G(\rho,r)| = |F(t,\theta)-F(r,\rho)| < \epsilon $ for this $\delta$ small enough.

2 - It is a very known fact that $f$ has degree zero if and only if it is homotopic to a constant. So, if the homotopy is a function $G$ as defined above, then you may take $G(\theta,0) = f$ (we are 'starting' with $f$) and $G(\theta,0) = c_0$ (we are 'ending' with the constant function $c_0$.

3 - We have already a function $G$ which is well defined on $\Bbb{S}^1 \times (0,1)$ that is a homotopy function. By polar coordinates representation, we may take $D$ as this product. But then we may 'reverse' the process of the topic 1, in which we obtained the homotopy from the extension, to obtain an extension from the homotopy.